# Add a specific close reason that covers product recommendations

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Fixing close question descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126719/fixing-close-question-descriptions)

It seems to me that one of the most common sources of close votes on serverfault is someone asking for a [shopping recommendation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).  Whatever option I choose from the list, will result in a message to the poster that doesn't clearly convey the message that shopping recommendation don't belong here.  The user will often complain in a comment or on meta.  To avoid that I am frequently adding a comment with a link to the blog post on the topic.

Since this type of question seems to be so common on serverfault and superuser, I think we should add dedicated close option for it so that when it does get close the user will get some specific help about why these questions are problematic.  I am getting annoyed at having to choose spend time posting a  comment, or see complaints in comments and on meta.

Comment: *This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion.* - Covered.

Comment: I am sorry, but very few of the people who complain are able to accept that polling = recommendation.  I understand it, but very few choose to understand that those two things are the same.

Comment: Just because people refuse to acknowledge that their question is not acceptable doesn't mean that it is...

Comment: @animuson, no, but I would like to close their questions using an automatic message, that actually gives them some useful information about why.

Comment: Whenever I close them, I leave the following [AutoComment](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/)`Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites because of their very limited lifespan. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.`

Comment: I like this idea.  Makes things immediately obvious and is much harder to argue with.

Answer (score 7):

The [Server Fault FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) explicitly states:

> If your question is about…
>
> > […]
>
> and it is not about…
>
> > […]
>
> - [Product, service, or learning material recommendations](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa)
>
> > […]
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Therefore, closing the question as **off topic** should be enough (and less debatable than  **not constructive**), since closing as **off topic** inserts the message:

> Questions on Server Fault are expected to generally relate to servers, networking, or desktop infrastructure, within the scope defined in the [faq](https://serverfault.com/faq).

That's what's being done on Super User, and the affected users seldom complain (some always will).

Answer (score 6):

I think that the "not constructive" close reason covers the reasons shopping recommendations are off topic. It says:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

A shopping recommendation asks for opinion, debate, and polling so I don't think another reason is needed for that in particular.

Comment: I agree, that should cover it.  But the comments I see from people lead to to believe that, the 'not constructive' description simply doesn't mean shopping recommendation.

Comment: It's true: _not constructive_ doesn't mean _shopping recommendation_, but it includes it. An answer for a question about shopping recommendations is probably giving the opinion of who writes it, as there isn't a definitive answer for those kind of questions.